# How do UPDATEs that use JOINs behave with multiple records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Say I have two tables like the ones below:

```
Table 1
ID  Total
1   2
2   4
3   6


Table 2
OtherId Value
1       1
1       2
```

And I perform the following UPDATE/JOIN query

```
update t1
set total = total + value
from Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2
ON t1.ID = t2.OtherId
```

How exactly is the addition of the values from Table2 applied?  I see two possible ways:

1. Table1 has the `Total` for record 1 updated twice with the value from the previous update taken into account each time.  So the first `Total` would be set to `2 + 1 = 3` and then the new value would be used in the next update: `3 + 2 = 5`.  So the final value would be 5
2. Table1 has the `Total` for record 1 updated twice but it doesn't take into account the previous update - it starts with the original value each time.  So the first update would still be `2 + 1 = 3` but the second update wouldn't take into account this new value so it would be `2 + 2 = 4`

I'm assuming that it would be the first method, but I couldn't find any documentation that went over how these types of updates are applied.  Can anyone provide me with details on how JOIN UPDATES behave in this type of situation?

Comment: Why not try it out? Hint....it won't be the first one because that would require aggregate data which you don't have in your query. It seems like you want aggregate data though.

Comment: any clustered indexes on these tables or are they heaps?

Comment: It is neither 1 or 2. SQL Server will pick an arbitrary value from the possible ones before doing the update. Often this will end up end up adding an aggregate operator using the  internal`ANY` aggregate though this can be hidden inside a distinct sort

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly it is case 2... and you cannot guarantee which update is the "final" result since you cannot specify order in an update statement and SQL has no inherent order.

```
declare @table1 table (id int, val int)
declare @table2 table (id int, val int)

insert into @table1
values (1,1)

insert into @table2 
values (1,2),(1,3)

select *
from @table1 t1
join @table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id

update t1 set val=t1.val+t2.val
from @table1 t1
join @table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id

select *
from @table1
```

[image: output]

Comment: Interesting - so it would be the second method not the first and there is no way to guarantee whether the result would be 5 or 3 consistently?

Comment: That is correct.  If you wanted to control it, you could use a CTE and a window function called `row_number()` to force the MIN or MAX value, or FIRST or LAST record based on say, an insertion date if you had it.  Or if you want the first methods (where both are cumulatively updated), you would have to aggregate table2 then update table1 with the aggregate.

Comment: what if you have a primary key on table2? Would this change the results @DaveCullum?

Comment: @scsimon I do not believe a PK would make the update 100% guaranteed to fire in the same order consistently.  I was trained that unless you specify order, you never know what the order will be the next time you hit execute, so I wouldn't rely on this in a business application.

Comment: [Proof](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/) that the clustered index does NOT guarantee order.